# Getting the number of function calls of fminsearch for each iteration

Tags: matlab, fminsearch

```
options = optimset('Display','iter','MaxIter',3,'OutputFcn',@outfun);
[x,fval,~,output] = fminsearch(@(param) esm6(param,identi),result(k,1:end-1),options);
```

This code will find the local Minimum of my esm6 function and due to the 'Display' Option it will Output strings like this

> Iteration   Func-count     min f(x)         Procedure
>        0            1          36.9193
>        1            5          35.9815         initial simplex
>        2            7          35.4924         contract inside
>        3            9          35.4924         contract inside
>        4           11          33.0085         expand

So in the command window, i get the function Count for each Iteration step. The structure `output`, which is created by fminsearch has only the total amount of func-count in it. Is there a way to receive all the Information, that is outputed in the command window also in the Output-structure?

EDIT:
I think i'm pretty Close to the solution. I wrote this outputfunction:

```
function stop = outfun(x,optimvalues,state);
    stop = false;
    if state == 'iter'
        history = evalin('base','history');
        history = [history; optimvalues.iteration optimvalues.funcCount];
        assignin('base','history',history);
    end
end
```

due to http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/output-functions.html this should work, but in fact, matlab tells me,

> ??? Reference to non-existent field 'funcCount'.

any idea, why this happens?

Comment: Pretty sure it will not solve your problem, but you should use `isequal` instead of `==` when comparing strings

Comment: You access a field by writting `mystruct.field1`, `mystruct.field2`,... So your error means that `optimvalues` is a structure with differents fields but there is no field named funcCount. Check the part of your code where you defined `optimvalues`.

Comment: By the way, I don't really understand your output function. You define `stop`as the output but stop will always equal to 0, so the function is pretty useless.

Comment: @BillBokeey: `strcmp` is probably the preferred means.

Comment: @Max: the online documentation is for the current, most recent, version of Matlab. Have you check the local documentation for your version to confirm that output functions work the same way and have the same parameters? And have you tried lower-casing to `optimvalues.funccount`? I think the field  may be capitalized differently in the `optimvalues` and `output` structures.

Comment: @BillBokeey why is `isequal` better? I took this from the example in the documentation, so i thought it would be good...

Comment: @obchardon i don't define `optimvalues` it just automatically exists for outputfunctions, check the linked documentation. And since it works for `optimvalues.iteration` I can be sure, that this is true, just the other field doesen't exist, even though it should, as it's written in the doc. And the thing about the stop-value is that as far as I understood it, an outputfunction has to have an output, that might stop the optimization `stop=true`. But since I do not want to stop the optimization, but use `MaxIter = 15`, I just set stop to `false` with no condition, as its done in the doc  i linked

Comment: @horchler sure, I use my local documentation, I just couldn't link that one, so I searched it in the online-doc. And yes, I already tried `funccount` and also `FuncCount`. Do you have any other suggestions for the fieldname?

Comment: I have to correct myself, it seems like I didn't tryout funccount, but just FuncCount. So at @horchler after realising you can Ctrl+D a builtin function and look in it, I found out, your solution was right. You might make it an answer and I will accept it.